# deleting files from local netbeans without removing it from server

Tags: html, netbeans, delete-file, remote-server

I am working on remote server using netbeans.
I wish to remove files or directories from my local computer without deleting it from server.
As for now I didn't find a way to do so.
Does anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just close Netbeans, then delete files or directories from computer and reopen Netbeans.
Files or directories were deleted only from locale project. At least it worked for me.
For my project > properties > Run configuration > Upload files: I have set to 'On Save'.